# How to fix UITextField background image not displayed after iOS14?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios14

In my project, I noticed after the ios14 update, UITextField background images are not working properly. i used these settings

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe apple will fix the problem in future updates. Meanwhile, I found the temporary solution with swift 4.2 hope it will be helpful for you

```
    func makeTextFieldBorderstyle(){
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        self.YourTextField1.borderStyle = .line
        self.YourTextField2.borderStyle = .line
        self.YourTextField3.borderStyle = .line
      } 
    }
```

call this **viewDidLoad**